# Is there a functional to create a version of a function with changed default arguments in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming

I'd like to create a variant of a function that behaves just like the original but has different default arguments. Is there a functional in base `R` or some package that does just that?

For example, since I use `ggrastr::geom_point_raster` often with `size = 0.2` and `raster.dpi = 600`, I would like to use `geom_single_cell <- <THE FUNCTIONAL I AM LOOKING FOR>(ggrastr::geom_point_raster, size = 0.2, raster.dpi = 600)` to create a new function `geom_single_cell` that behaves like `function(..., size = 0.2, raster.dpi = 600) ggrastr::geom_point_raster(..., size = size , raster.dpi =  raster.dpi)` but has the other `formals` of `ggrastr::geom_point_raster`. Apart from the benefit of code completion through the `formals` of the created fucntion, the desired functional would avoid the redundancy in `size = size , raster.dpi =  raster.dpi`.

I know there is `purrr::partial` but that does not allow overwriting the specified default (`purrr::partial(mean, na.rm = TRUE)(NA, na.rm = FALSE)` does error).

Do you know where to find `<THE FUNCTIONAL I AM LOOKING FOR>`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a functional solution, but you might find the package default with the ```default()``` and ```default <- ``` functions interesting.

Comment: aren't you overthinking it? `geom_single_cell <- function(..., size = 0.2, raster.dpi = 600){ggrastr::geom_point_raster(..., size = size, raster.dpi = raster.dpi)}`

Comment: @NiklasvMoers the `default` package looked promising but does not allow to specify arguments in `...` ( e.g. the `mean` example does not work for that reason)

Comment: @Edo yes ^^, at least when asking the question! But this is precisely what I currently use in my code.  However, this solution has two disadvantages over a functional: the redundant `size = size, raster.dpi = raster.dpi` and the missing `formals` of `geom_single_cell `. I changed the question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Oh and this approach does not handle missing arguments as desired: `(function(a = 5) (function(a) missing(a))(a = a))(a = )` returns `FALSE`. This is relevant for the `ggplot` in the question, when I would like to exceptionally use size as an aesthetic I would specify `geom_single_cell(aes(size = whatever), size = )` (But I have not thought this through)